# how to include single quotes from user input in perl

Tags: perl

The user is going to enter input string such as Tom's Toy.
However the perl script complains saying "unmatched '."

This is my code.

```
my $commandline="";
while (@ARGV) {
  $_ = shift @ARGV;
  {$commandline .= $_ . ' ';}
}
print " Running $commandline\n";
system ($commandline);
```

Now if the user input is Tom's Toy. I just want to print back Tom's Toy.
However perl complains "unmatched '.".
IF I dont user quote it works fine. (for eg: Tom Toy is good)
How do  I fix this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: my $commandline = join ' ', @ARGV;

Answer (score 4):

If you switch things around a little to use the `system $cmd, @args` version of the function, no shell will be invoked, so no escaping will be necessary.

```
my $cmd = shift @ARGV;
my @args = @ARGV;
print " Running $cmd\n";

system $cmd, @args;
```

I tested with `./test.pl echo Tom\'s Toy` and it gives the expected output:

```
 Running echo
Tom's Toy
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However in the code you mentioned the input still needs to be specified as "hello y\'all" with the backslash. Is there a way we can ignore the backslash in user input and still come up with the correct solution?

Comment: @Bhar - the backslash is for the shell, not perl. Different shells may have different escaping requirements but you can't get around it completely

Answer (score 2):

system(@ARGV) is probably all you need.

If you give system() a single argument, *and* if that argument contains any shell metacharacters (including spaces, quotation marks, etc), then the argument will be passed to the shell.  jwodder is quite correct: the error message is from the shell, not from Perl.

If you pass system() multiple arguments, it's done without invoking a shell -- which is usually better.  The approach you're using takes your program's command-line arguments, joins them together into a single string, then passes that string to the shell, which splits it back into multiple arguments for execution.

On the other hand, sometimes you might *want* to invoke the shell, for example if you're building up a complex command using pipes, I/O redirection, and so forth, and you don't want to set it all up in Perl.  But you have to be careful about metacharacters, as you've seen.

"perldoc -f system" explains this more fully.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is print back the user input, use `print`, not `system`.  `system` will try to pass the supplied string to the shell for execution as a command, and it's the shell that's complaining about the unmatched quote.

(Also, instead of manually concatenating `@ARGV`, may I direct your attention to the [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) function?)

Comment: I tried a simple print. But still the result is same. Perl for some reason complains when the user input has a single quote(unmatched 1)